# iOS: Boxed table view cells with background image not filling the whole width of screen?

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm wondering what's the easiest way to create a complex table view cell like in the attachement? So far I've designed all cells in Interface builder. 
Do you have any example code for that? I couldn't find any tutorial covering this…
[image]

Comment: What problem u face in interface builder?

Comment: post screenshots from ib

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell by subclassing the uitableviewcell which will be better. In that custom cell, you can add label and uiimageview for achieving above design.

Please refer the following links

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've read through these and I've almost got it but I face problems with a) The accessory views…since my background has a space on both sides, the accessory view isn't placed in the cell. And b) the edit of the table messes everything up...

Comment: for that you just create a small uiimageview with accessory arrow image. Because we cant change the position of accessoryview.

Comment: Ok and the indenting I have to try. And last 2 questions: How can I edit the highlight part of the cell or just say don't highlight anything if selected? Because otherwise the whole background cell is selected and this looks ugly :) And where do I link this background image to? To the cell or or the the view controller and set it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: better to use custom view and lay those fields in a UIScrollView. If you try tableview cell you would face lot of problem like your background will fill partly and it doesnot give you the looks as you want. So i will recommend you to use Custom view and UIScrollView to achieve best result.

Comment: for the purpose of selection, u need to create an image in size of the  contetnt(ie, other sides are transparent). create uiimageview with this image. set self.selectedBackgroundView = bgView; you need to link the background image to the cell instead of viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for your advice. So I link it to the cell but set the image and the selected Background in the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the ViewController correct?

Comment: yes. you can give it in cellForRowAtIndexPath in the ViewController